# Count unique once-occuring elements in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq

I have this problem

```
Structure Person
    Dim name As String
    Dim age As Integer
End Structure

Dim people(10) As Person

people(0).name = "A"
people(0).age = 21
...
people(9).name = "Z"
people(9).age = 30
```

Now e.g. if I have the following values for `age = {20, 21, 20, 23, 25, 35, 30, 29, 25, 26}`

I am trying to identify and eliminate every person from `people` who has a unique age, i.e., my final `people` array should only contain records of persons with ages `20,25`.

I tried something like this:

```
tempList() As Int
cleanList() As Int

for i = 0 to people.count - 1
     array.resize(templist, i + 1)
     templist(i) = people(i).age
next

cleanList = tempList.Distinct().ToArray()
```

The problem is, doing it this way gives me each and every distinct value from the array. But I want only those values which occur only once.

Any help on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `.age` and get the items from the groups that have more than one item:

```
Dim cleanList = people.ToLookup(Function(p) p.age).
                       Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1).SelectMany(Function(g) g).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your list of ages first to get only the repeated values:

```
Dim ages= From a In allages _
          Group a By Key = a Into Group _
          Where Group.Count() > 1 _
          Select Group.Key
```

Then you can filter you list of people:

```
Dim result = From p In people _
             Where ages.Contains(p.age)  _
             Select p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim duplicatePersons = people.Where(Function(p) people.Count(Function(p1) p1.Age = p.Age) > 1).ToArray()
```